# Dynamically change form action and placeholder text

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a drop down menu and text field.  The placeholder text dynamically changes in the text field based on the selected option. It is working for all the options except one; the google search.

I am able to change the form action from the first, normal url and id to the google url and id.  However, because the google id is more complex (ex. searchbox_test45656456:test-_test), the id and action do not change.

Any help is appreciated. I know I my code is not the most conventional and efficient.  I figure if I can learn how to fix this, then I can learn how to improve it.

If changing the placeholder text dynamically using a class is the better way to go, any help getting there is also appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptb/rxskhqj1/5/)

So far this code below has not worked.

```
$('#searchForm').on('change', function() {
    var placeholder = $(this).find(':selected').data('placeholder');
    var select_option = $('#search_catalog option:selected').attr('class');
```

**UPDATED**
I'm getting closer, the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptb/rxskhqj1/16/) is now working using a class and id onchange element instead of the form. The remaining issue I am having is that one i change the select option to website only, which is the google search, if i change the select option again, while other elements in my code change correctly, the form id and action do not.

I'm still researching this but any pointers in the right direction would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `searchForm` your `<form>`? Maybe you should reference an input element in the form rather than the form itself.

Comment: Your right!  The next problem I am having is that I have only successfully made an onchange action with a select based on the value.  In this case I want to make the change based on the select option class.